# Is there any way I can tell typescript the signature of a class method when I'm calling said method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, graphql

So I have a graphql server that uses a datasource. This is the definition:

```js
type GetStudentFn = (id: string, env?: 'dev'|'prod') => Promise<any>;
class StudentsAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.baseUrl = 'http://someurl.com/';
  }

  async getStudent(...[id,env]: Parameters<GetStudentFn>) {
    console.log(env)
    return this.get(`someurl/${id}`)
  }
```

The `GetStudentFn` type alias works perfectly within the class. The problem comes when I try to call the method of that class in my resolver.

```js
const resolvers = {
     Query: {
       student: (root, args, { dataSources }) => {
          return dataSources.StudentsAPI.getStudent(args.id);
       }
     }
   }
```

How can I use `GetStudentFn` to make sure I'm calling the `dataSources.StudentsAPI.getStudent()` method correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you can tell typescript that something has an specific type with the as keyword:
class Foo {
}

```
class SpecificFoo extends Foo {
    specificFooMethod() : void {
    }
}

function getSomeFoo():Foo {
    return new Foo();
}

(getSomeFoo() as SpecificFoo).specificFooMethod();
```

For you example:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        student: (root, args, { dataSources }) => {
            return (dataSources.StudentsAPI as StudentsAPI).getStudent(args.id);
        }
    }
}
```